# Ubuntu typing 'php' in terminal shows a lot of errors

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and php is installed and working perfectly. But, when I type `php` in the terminal, it lists a lot of errors (and after that, it goes to work perfectly) as below :

```
MIB search path: /home/kevin/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 10 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 34 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 37 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
Did not find 'enterprises' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'TruthValue' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdavis ::= { enterprises 2021 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 39 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'ucdExperimental' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: ucdDlmodMIB ::= { ucdExperimental 14 }
Undefined identifier: ucdExperimental near line 13 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (MTA-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NETWORK-SERVICES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 15 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'ucdExperimental' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: ucdDiskIOMIB ::= { ucdExperimental 15 }
Undefined identifier: ucdExperimental near line 19 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 15 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'ucdExperimental' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmSensors ::= { ucdExperimental 16 }
Undefined identifier: ucdExperimental near line 32 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Did not find 'ucdavis' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DEMO-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoMIB ::= { ucdavis 14 }
Undefined identifier: ucdavis near line 7 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DEMO-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMP-TARGET-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 9 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 8 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-MIB.txt
Did not find 'enterprises' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmp ::= { enterprises 8072 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 10 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 21 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Did not find 'SnmpAdminString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmpObjects' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmpModuleIDs' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmpNotifications' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmpGroups' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'RowStatus' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'TruthValue' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsAgentNotifyGroup ::= { netSnmpGroups 9 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 545 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactionGroup ::= { netSnmpGroups 8 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 536 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsConfigGroups ::= { netSnmpGroups 7 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 515 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheGroup ::= { netSnmpGroups 4 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 505 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsModuleGroup ::= { netSnmpGroups 2 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 495 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: netSnmpAgentMIB ::= { netSnmpModuleIDs 2 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpModuleIDs near line 24 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactions ::= { netSnmpObjects 8 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 55 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsConfiguration ::= { netSnmpObjects 7 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 54 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsErrorHistory ::= { netSnmpObjects 6 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 53 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCache ::= { netSnmpObjects 5 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 52 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDLMod ::= { netSnmpObjects 4 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 51 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsExtensions ::= { netSnmpObjects 3 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 50 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsMibRegistry ::= { netSnmpObjects 2 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 49 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsVersion ::= { netSnmpObjects 1 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 48 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyRestart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 3 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpNotifications near line 482 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyShutdown ::= { netSnmpNotifications 2 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpNotifications near line 476 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyStart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 1 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpNotifications near line 470 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-ICMP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-FORWARD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 10 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 10 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 12 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (INET-ADDRESS-MIB): At line 13 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
Did not find 'SnmpAdminString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmp' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'RowStatus' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'StorageType' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'InetAddressType' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'InetAddress' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExamples ::= { netSnmp 2 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmp near line 16 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
Did not find 'SnmpAdminString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmpExamples' in module NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB: netSnmpPassExamples ::= { netSnmpExamples 255 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpExamples near line 14 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 16 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
Did not find 'nsExtensions' in module NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'RowStatus' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'StorageType' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendGroups ::= { nsExtensions 3 }
Undefined identifier: nsExtensions near line 39 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendObjects ::= { nsExtensions 2 }
Undefined identifier: nsExtensions near line 38 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: netSnmpExtendMIB ::= { nsExtensions 1 }
Undefined identifier: nsExtensions near line 19 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 9 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 16 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 25 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt
Did not find 'SnmpAdminString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmpObjects' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmpGroups' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'vacmGroupName' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'vacmAccessContextPrefix' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'vacmAccessSecurityModel' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'vacmAccessSecurityLevel' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'RowStatus' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'StorageType' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB: netSnmpVacmMIB ::= { netSnmpObjects 9 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 28 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchRegExCompilation ::= { logMatchEntry 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchErrorFlag ::= { logMatchEntry 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCycle ::= { logMatchEntry 11 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCount ::= { logMatchEntry 10 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCounter ::= { logMatchEntry 9 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCurrentCount ::= { logMatchEntry 8 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCurrentCounter ::= { logMatchEntry 7 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchGlobalCount ::= { logMatchEntry 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchGlobalCounter ::= { logMatchEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchRegEx ::= { logMatchEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchFilename ::= { logMatchEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchName ::= { logMatchEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchIndex ::= { logMatchEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB: nsVacmAccessEntry ::= { nsVacmAccessTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extErrFixCmd ::= { extEntry 103 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extErrFix ::= { extEntry 102 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extOutput ::= { extEntry 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extResult ::= { extEntry 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extCommand ::= { extEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extNames ::= { extEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extIndex ::= { extEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoPublic ::= { ucdDemoMIBObjects 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodTable ::= { ucdDlmodMIB 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodNextIndex ::= { ucdDlmodMIB 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExamples ::= { netSnmp 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpConformance ::= { netSnmp 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpNotificationPrefix ::= { netSnmp 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpExperimental ::= { netSnmp 9999 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpEnumerations ::= { netSnmp 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpObjects ::= { netSnmp 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionDoDebugging ::= { version 20 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionSavePersistentData ::= { version 13 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionRestartAgent ::= { version 12 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionUpdateConfig ::= { version 11 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionClearCache ::= { version 10 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionConfigureOptions ::= { version 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionIdent ::= { version 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionCDate ::= { version 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionDate ::= { version 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionTag ::= { version 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionIndex ::= { version 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleHeartbeatNotification ::= { netSnmpExampleNotificationPrefix 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheStatus ::= { nsCacheEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheTimeout ::= { nsCacheEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCachedOID ::= { nsCacheEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: unknown ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 255 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dragonfly ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 17 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: macosx ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 16 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: aix ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 15 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: hpux11 ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 14 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: win32 ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 13 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: openbsd ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 12 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: bsdi ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 11 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: linux ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 10 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: irix ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 9 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: freebsd ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 8 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: netbsd1 ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 7 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: hpux10 ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ultrix ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: osf ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: solaris ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: sunos4 ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: hpux9 ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutputGroup ::= { nsExtendGroups 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendConfigGroup ::= { nsExtendGroups 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOEntry ::= { diskIOTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactionEntry ::= { nsTransactionTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpGroups ::= { netSnmpConformance 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpCompliances ::= { netSnmpConformance 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: mrModuleName ::= { mrEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: mrIndex ::= { mrEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDebugTokenEntry ::= { nsDebugTokenTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendStatus ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 21 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendStorage ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 20 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendRunType ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 7 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendExecType ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendCacheTime ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendInput ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendArgs ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendCommand ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendToken ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsModuleTable ::= { nsMibRegistry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpPlaypen ::= { netSnmpExperimental 9999 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpIETFWGEntry ::= { netSnmpIETFWGTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prErrFixCmd ::= { prEntry 103 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prErrFix ::= { prEntry 102 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prErrMessage ::= { prEntry 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prErrorFlag ::= { prEntry 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prCount ::= { prEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prMax ::= { prEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prMin ::= { prEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prNames ::= { prEntry 2 }
...
...
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIONWrittenX ::= { diskIOEntry 13 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIONReadX ::= { diskIOEntry 12 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOLA15 ::= { diskIOEntry 11 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOLA5 ::= { diskIOEntry 10 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOLA1 ::= { diskIOEntry 9 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOWrites ::= { diskIOEntry 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOReads ::= { diskIOEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIONWritten ::= { diskIOEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIONRead ::= { diskIOEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIODevice ::= { diskIOEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOIndex ::= { diskIOEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactionMode ::= { nsTransactionEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactionID ::= { nsTransactionEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDebugTokenStatus ::= { nsDebugTokenEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDebugTokenPrefix ::= { nsDebugTokenEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: nsIETFWGChair2 ::= { netSnmpIETFWGEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: nsIETFWGChair1 ::= { netSnmpIETFWGEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: nsIETFWGName ::= { netSnmpIETFWGEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLoggingTable ::= { nsConfigLogging 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostsEntry ::= { netSnmpHostsTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodStatus ::= { dlmodEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodError ::= { dlmodEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodPath ::= { dlmodEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodName ::= { dlmodEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodIndex ::= { dlmodEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmMiscSensorsValue ::= { lmMiscSensorsEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmMiscSensorsDevice ::= { lmMiscSensorsEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmMiscSensorsIndex ::= { lmMiscSensorsEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB: netSnmpPassEntry ::= { netSnmpPassTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmSensors ::= { ucdExperimental 16 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: ucdDiskIOMIB ::= { ucdExperimental 15 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: ucdDlmodMIB ::= { ucdExperimental 14 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskEntry ::= { dskTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: netSnmpAgentMIB ::= { netSnmpModuleIDs 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmFanSensorsValue ::= { lmFanSensorsEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmFanSensorsDevice ::= { lmFanSensorsEntry 2 }
...
...
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: fileSize ::= { fileEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: fileName ::= { fileEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: fileIndex ::= { fileEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput2Table ::= { nsExtendObjects 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput1Table ::= { nsExtendObjects 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendConfigTable ::= { nsExtendObjects 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendNumEntries ::= { nsExtendObjects 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput1Entry ::= { nsExtendOutput1Table 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawGuestNice ::= { systemStats 66 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawGuest ::= { systemStats 65 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawSteal ::= { systemStats 64 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssRawSwapOut ::= { systemStats 63 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssRawSwapIn ::= { systemStats 62 }
...
...
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssIOReceive ::= { systemStats 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssIOSent ::= { systemStats 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssSwapOut ::= { systemStats 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssSwapIn ::= { systemStats 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssErrorName ::= { systemStats 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssIndex ::= { systemStats 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput2Entry ::= { nsExtendOutput2Table 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laEntry ::= { laTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheTable ::= { nsCache 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheEnabled ::= { nsCache 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheDefaultTimeout ::= { nsCache 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchEntry ::= { logMatchTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extEntry ::= { extTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsConfigLogging ::= { nsConfiguration 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsConfigDebug ::= { nsConfiguration 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleString ::= { netSnmpExampleScalars 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleSleeper ::= { netSnmpExampleScalars 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleInteger ::= { netSnmpExampleScalars 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmVoltSensorsValue ::= { lmVoltSensorsEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoUserList ::= { ucdDemoPublic 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoPublicString ::= { ucdDemoPublic 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoResetKeys ::= { ucdDemoPublic 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleHeartbeatName ::= { netSnmpExampleNotificationObjects 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleHeartbeatRate ::= { netSnmpExampleNotificationObjects 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB: netSnmpPassExamples ::= { netSnmpExamples 255 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleNotifications ::= { netSnmpExamples 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleTables ::= { netSnmpExamples 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleScalars ::= { netSnmpExamples 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB: nsVacmAccessTable ::= { netSnmpVacmMIB 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdShutdown ::= { ucdTraps 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdStart ::= { ucdTraps 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmMiscSensorsTable ::= { lmSensors 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmVoltSensorsTable ::= { lmSensors 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmSensorsMIB ::= { lmSensors 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: mrEntry ::= { mrTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendConfigEntry ::= { nsExtendConfigTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostRowStatus ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostStorage ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostAddress ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostAddressType ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostName ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prEntry ::= { prTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleNotification ::= { netSnmpExampleNotifications 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleNotificationObjects ::= { netSnmpExampleNotifications 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleNotificationPrefix ::= { netSnmpExampleNotifications 0 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostsTable ::= { netSnmpExampleTables 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsVersion ::= { netSnmpObjects 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsMibRegistry ::= { netSnmpObjects 2 }
...
...
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogStatus ::= { nsLoggingEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogMaxLevel ::= { nsLoggingEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogType ::= { nsLoggingEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogToken ::= { nsLoggingEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogLevel ::= { nsLoggingEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendResult ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutNumLines ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutputFull ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput1Line ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutLine ::= { nsExtendOutput2Entry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendLineIndex ::= { nsExtendOutput2Entry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyStart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyShutdown ::= { netSnmpNotifications 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyRestart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laErrMessage ::= { laEntry 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laErrorFlag ::= { laEntry 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoadFloat ::= { laEntry 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoadInt ::= { laEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laConfig ::= { laEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoad ::= { laEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laNames ::= { laEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laIndex ::= { laEntry 1 }
```

What is the problem here and does it affect anything? Thanks!

Comment: Check if `libsnmp-base` is installed

Comment: @tlenss it shows, its already the newest version

Comment: Did you try apt-get remove and then apt-get install to reinstall from scratch with all dependencies?

Comment: for php7, just type sudo apt-get remove php7.0-snmp
I got a lot of error when I am installing all the php packages `sudo apt-get install php7.0*` thank you  @Dr. Tyrell answer

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Simply remove php5-snmp package. You can use this command in a console to do so:

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-snmp
```

With PHP 7, the package is php7.0-snmp:

```
sudo apt-get remove php7.0-snmp
```

Comment: How to I remove php5-snmp package?

Comment: It really depends if your PHP was or wasn't compiled with snmp support ("--with-snmp" configuration option, which is basically the same of having the package 'php5-snmp' installed). 

If your PHP was compiled with snmp support you should check if snmp package is installed on your system (apt-get install snmp). If you don't care about PHP supporting snmp at all, just remove the config "--with-snmp" of your ./configure command or remove "php5-snmp" in case you use packages.

Comment: I would use `purge` instead of `remove` to delete the remaining  `/etc/php5/conf.d/snmp.ini` file that tries to load the just removed snmp module.

Comment: Mine solved using `sudo apt-get install snmp` as mentioned by @bruno-sauza, since one of our web app is using php5-snmp.

Comment: Minor addition: for php 7 you should use
`sudo apt-get remove php7.0-snmp`

Comment: For PHP7 rather than uninstalling it: `sudo phpdismod snmp` solves it. If you are using FPM make sure to do `sudo service php-7.0-fpm restart` or `sudo service php-7.1-fpm restart`. Apache and Nginx without FPM shouldn't need a restart.

Comment: Be careful not to remove apps you actively use that may be dependent on this. One example is cacti. Always review what aptitude is going to remove before clicking Y.

Answer (score 90):

For those of us that need the `php5-snmp` package, the above may not solve your problem. In that case you can try:

```
sudo apt-get install snmp
```

which will install snmp for you, which seems to be required for the `php5-snmp` package to avoid outputting those errors.

Answer (score 24):

```
apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader
```

Isn't this the best answer? Found @ https://serverfault.com/questions/440285/why-does-snmp-fail-to-use-its-own-mibs

Comment: agreed this is the best answer - in order for the error to exist the user must have installed `php-snmp` at some stage, most probably a requirement of a package or framework etc.

Comment: I'm trying to give access to a user inside a jail.  PHP works fine no the host, but I get a bunch of "Cannot find module" errors such as `Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB)`.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using php 5. Simply remove php5-snmp package

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-snmp
```

If you're using php 7. Remove php7.0-snmp package.

```
sudo apt-get remove php7.0-snmp
```

Answer (score 8):

This also helped me. 
`sudo apt-get install snmp`

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/installed-php-7-0-now-returns-errors

Comment: Aso helped me with php5

Answer (score 2):

You should try a reinstall through apt-get

```
sudo apt-get remove php
sudo apt-get install php
```

In most cases it is enough to just reinstall the offending extension.

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-snmp
```

Comment: removing the extension and installing again is enough

Comment: added better solution from @dr-tyrell below since original poster choose this one as accepted. kudos to dr-tyrell of course!

Comment: This helped me find the best solution for my self - `sudo apt-get remove php7.0-snmp`, followed by `dpkg --purge php7.0-snmp`, then reinstalled it via `sudo apt-get php7.0-snmp`. After executing these commands, `php -i` no longer displayed the errors it did prior.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and if it not help, try to reinstall php

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge php5
sudo apt-get install php5
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

this error display in cacti poller error logs when snmp-mibs-downloader not installed

`vim /etc/apt/sources.list`

add to sources "non-free" packages

`apt-get update
 apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

These warning messages appear because the PHP init can not find the mod config in the user dir. So you have to do the following steps:

1) edit your `etc/php/{yourversion}/mods-available/snmp.ini` and comment or delete the following strings:

```
; configuration for php snmp module
; priority=20
;extension=snmp.so
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
~
```

2) run `apt-get --purge remove php-snmpt`

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours on this and wanted to share how I solved it in case someone searches for this error and still needs to use php-snmp module (removing that module also removes the error).
/etc/snmp/snmp.conf has a setting: `mibs ALL`

This tells the net-snmp library to attempt to load every mib file. If you do not need this you can comment that out and the errors are gone. If you still want to load every mib file continue reading.

In ubuntu 16.04 setting the environment MIBDIR to /usr/share/mibs stopped these errors for me. I needed this to happen on every session for php CLI runs so I created
/etc/profile.d/mibs.sh with: `export MIBDIRS=/usr/share/mibs`

No more php errors from CLI.

To disable the error for cronjobs I added the same ENV in the cron file where the errors were happening.

If someone knows why not setting MIBDIRS causes these errors, I would love to hear. I can only assume the default for this in net-snmp are not compatible with ubuntu 16.04 mibs downloader.