# Running PHP gives lots of 'snmp' errors in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

I get the following problem when I run `php` command in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
MIB search path: /home/kevin/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 10 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 34 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 37 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
Did not find 'enterprises' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'TruthValue' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdavis ::= { enterprises 2021 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 39 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'ucdExperimental' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: ucdDlmodMIB ::= { ucdExperimental 14 }
Undefined identifier: ucdExperimental near line 13 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (MTA-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NETWORK-SERVICES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 15 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'ucdExperimental' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: ucdDiskIOMIB ::= { ucdExperimental 15 }
Undefined identifier: ucdExperimental near line 19 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 15 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'ucdExperimental' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmSensors ::= { ucdExperimental 16 }
Undefined identifier: ucdExperimental near line 32 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Did not find 'ucdavis' in module UCD-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DEMO-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoMIB ::= { ucdavis 14 }
Undefined identifier: ucdavis near line 7 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DEMO-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMP-TARGET-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 9 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 8 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-MIB.txt
Did not find 'enterprises' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmp ::= { enterprises 8072 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 10 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 21 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Did not find 'SnmpAdminString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmpObjects' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmpModuleIDs' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmpNotifications' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmpGroups' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'RowStatus' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'TruthValue' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsAgentNotifyGroup ::= { netSnmpGroups 9 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 545 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactionGroup ::= { netSnmpGroups 8 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 536 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsConfigGroups ::= { netSnmpGroups 7 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 515 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheGroup ::= { netSnmpGroups 4 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 505 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsModuleGroup ::= { netSnmpGroups 2 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpGroups near line 495 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: netSnmpAgentMIB ::= { netSnmpModuleIDs 2 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpModuleIDs near line 24 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactions ::= { netSnmpObjects 8 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 55 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsConfiguration ::= { netSnmpObjects 7 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 54 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsErrorHistory ::= { netSnmpObjects 6 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 53 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCache ::= { netSnmpObjects 5 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 52 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDLMod ::= { netSnmpObjects 4 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 51 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsExtensions ::= { netSnmpObjects 3 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 50 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsMibRegistry ::= { netSnmpObjects 2 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 49 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsVersion ::= { netSnmpObjects 1 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 48 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyRestart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 3 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpNotifications near line 482 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyShutdown ::= { netSnmpNotifications 2 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpNotifications near line 476 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyStart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 1 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpNotifications near line 470 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-ICMP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-FORWARD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 10 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 10 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 12 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (INET-ADDRESS-MIB): At line 13 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
Did not find 'SnmpAdminString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmp' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'RowStatus' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'StorageType' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'InetAddressType' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'InetAddress' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExamples ::= { netSnmp 2 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmp near line 16 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt
Did not find 'SnmpAdminString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmpExamples' in module NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB: netSnmpPassExamples ::= { netSnmpExamples 255 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpExamples near line 14 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 16 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
Did not find 'nsExtensions' in module NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'RowStatus' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'StorageType' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendGroups ::= { nsExtensions 3 }
Undefined identifier: nsExtensions near line 39 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendObjects ::= { nsExtensions 2 }
Undefined identifier: nsExtensions near line 38 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: netSnmpExtendMIB ::= { nsExtensions 1 }
Undefined identifier: nsExtensions near line 19 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 9 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 16 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 25 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt
Did not find 'SnmpAdminString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmpObjects' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'netSnmpGroups' in module NET-SNMP-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'vacmGroupName' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'vacmAccessContextPrefix' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'vacmAccessSecurityModel' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'vacmAccessSecurityLevel' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'RowStatus' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'StorageType' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB: netSnmpVacmMIB ::= { netSnmpObjects 9 }
Undefined identifier: netSnmpObjects near line 28 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchRegExCompilation ::= { logMatchEntry 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchErrorFlag ::= { logMatchEntry 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCycle ::= { logMatchEntry 11 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCount ::= { logMatchEntry 10 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCounter ::= { logMatchEntry 9 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCurrentCount ::= { logMatchEntry 8 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchCurrentCounter ::= { logMatchEntry 7 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchGlobalCount ::= { logMatchEntry 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchGlobalCounter ::= { logMatchEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchRegEx ::= { logMatchEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchFilename ::= { logMatchEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchName ::= { logMatchEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: logMatchIndex ::= { logMatchEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB: nsVacmAccessEntry ::= { nsVacmAccessTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extErrFixCmd ::= { extEntry 103 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extErrFix ::= { extEntry 102 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extOutput ::= { extEntry 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extResult ::= { extEntry 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extCommand ::= { extEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extNames ::= { extEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: extIndex ::= { extEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoPublic ::= { ucdDemoMIBObjects 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodTable ::= { ucdDlmodMIB 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodNextIndex ::= { ucdDlmodMIB 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExamples ::= { netSnmp 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpConformance ::= { netSnmp 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpNotificationPrefix ::= { netSnmp 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpExperimental ::= { netSnmp 9999 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpEnumerations ::= { netSnmp 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpObjects ::= { netSnmp 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionDoDebugging ::= { version 20 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionSavePersistentData ::= { version 13 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionRestartAgent ::= { version 12 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionUpdateConfig ::= { version 11 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionClearCache ::= { version 10 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionConfigureOptions ::= { version 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionIdent ::= { version 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionCDate ::= { version 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionDate ::= { version 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionTag ::= { version 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: versionIndex ::= { version 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleHeartbeatNotification ::= { netSnmpExampleNotificationPrefix 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheStatus ::= { nsCacheEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCacheTimeout ::= { nsCacheEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsCachedOID ::= { nsCacheEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: unknown ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 255 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dragonfly ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 17 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: macosx ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 16 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: aix ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 15 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: hpux11 ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 14 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: win32 ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 13 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: openbsd ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 12 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: bsdi ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 11 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: linux ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 10 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: irix ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 9 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: freebsd ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 8 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: netbsd1 ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 7 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: hpux10 ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ultrix ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: osf ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: solaris ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: sunos4 ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: hpux9 ::= { ucdSnmpAgent 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutputGroup ::= { nsExtendGroups 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendConfigGroup ::= { nsExtendGroups 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOEntry ::= { diskIOTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactionEntry ::= { nsTransactionTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpGroups ::= { netSnmpConformance 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpCompliances ::= { netSnmpConformance 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: mrModuleName ::= { mrEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: mrIndex ::= { mrEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDebugTokenEntry ::= { nsDebugTokenTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendStatus ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 21 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendStorage ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 20 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendRunType ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 7 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendExecType ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendCacheTime ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendInput ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendArgs ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendCommand ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendToken ::= { nsExtendConfigEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsModuleTable ::= { nsMibRegistry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-MIB: netSnmpPlaypen ::= { netSnmpExperimental 9999 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpIETFWGEntry ::= { netSnmpIETFWGTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prErrFixCmd ::= { prEntry 103 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prErrFix ::= { prEntry 102 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prErrMessage ::= { prEntry 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prErrorFlag ::= { prEntry 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prCount ::= { prEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prMax ::= { prEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prMin ::= { prEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prNames ::= { prEntry 2 }
...
...
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIONWrittenX ::= { diskIOEntry 13 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIONReadX ::= { diskIOEntry 12 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOLA15 ::= { diskIOEntry 11 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOLA5 ::= { diskIOEntry 10 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOLA1 ::= { diskIOEntry 9 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOWrites ::= { diskIOEntry 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOReads ::= { diskIOEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIONWritten ::= { diskIOEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIONRead ::= { diskIOEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIODevice ::= { diskIOEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOIndex ::= { diskIOEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactionMode ::= { nsTransactionEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactionID ::= { nsTransactionEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDebugTokenStatus ::= { nsDebugTokenEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDebugTokenPrefix ::= { nsDebugTokenEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: nsIETFWGChair2 ::= { netSnmpIETFWGEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: nsIETFWGChair1 ::= { netSnmpIETFWGEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: nsIETFWGName ::= { netSnmpIETFWGEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLoggingTable ::= { nsConfigLogging 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostsEntry ::= { netSnmpHostsTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodStatus ::= { dlmodEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodError ::= { dlmodEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodPath ::= { dlmodEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodName ::= { dlmodEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: dlmodIndex ::= { dlmodEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmMiscSensorsValue ::= { lmMiscSensorsEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmMiscSensorsDevice ::= { lmMiscSensorsEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmMiscSensorsIndex ::= { lmMiscSensorsEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB: netSnmpPassEntry ::= { netSnmpPassTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmSensors ::= { ucdExperimental 16 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: ucdDiskIOMIB ::= { ucdExperimental 15 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DLMOD-MIB: ucdDlmodMIB ::= { ucdExperimental 14 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskEntry ::= { dskTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: netSnmpAgentMIB ::= { netSnmpModuleIDs 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmFanSensorsValue ::= { lmFanSensorsEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmFanSensorsDevice ::= { lmFanSensorsEntry 2 }
...
...
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: fileSize ::= { fileEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: fileName ::= { fileEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: fileIndex ::= { fileEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput2Table ::= { nsExtendObjects 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput1Table ::= { nsExtendObjects 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendConfigTable ::= { nsExtendObjects 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendNumEntries ::= { nsExtendObjects 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput1Entry ::= { nsExtendOutput1Table 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawGuestNice ::= { systemStats 66 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawGuest ::= { systemStats 65 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssCpuRawSteal ::= { systemStats 64 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssRawSwapOut ::= { systemStats 63 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssRawSwapIn ::= { systemStats 62 }
...
...
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssIOReceive ::= { systemStats 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssIOSent ::= { systemStats 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssSwapOut ::= { systemStats 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssSwapIn ::= { systemStats 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssErrorName ::= { systemStats 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ssIndex ::= { systemStats 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput2Entry ::= { nsExtendOutput2Table 1 }
    Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleInteger ::= { netSnmpExampleScalars 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmVoltSensorsValue ::= { lmVoltSensorsEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoUserList ::= { ucdDemoPublic 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoPublicString ::= { ucdDemoPublic 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DEMO-MIB: ucdDemoResetKeys ::= { ucdDemoPublic 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleHeartbeatName ::= { netSnmpExampleNotificationObjects 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleHeartbeatRate ::= { netSnmpExampleNotificationObjects 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB: netSnmpPassExamples ::= { netSnmpExamples 255 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleNotifications ::= { netSnmpExamples 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleTables ::= { netSnmpExamples 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleScalars ::= { netSnmpExamples 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB: nsVacmAccessTable ::= { netSnmpVacmMIB 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdShutdown ::= { ucdTraps 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: ucdStart ::= { ucdTraps 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmMiscSensorsTable ::= { lmSensors 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmVoltSensorsTable ::= { lmSensors 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in LM-SENSORS-MIB: lmSensorsMIB ::= { lmSensors 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: mrEntry ::= { mrTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendConfigEntry ::= { nsExtendConfigTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostRowStatus ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostStorage ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostAddress ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostAddressType ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostName ::= { netSnmpHostsEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: prEntry ::= { prTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleNotification ::= { netSnmpExampleNotifications 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleNotificationObjects ::= { netSnmpExampleNotifications 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpExampleNotificationPrefix ::= { netSnmpExampleNotifications 0 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB: netSnmpHostsTable ::= { netSnmpExampleTables 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsVersion ::= { netSnmpObjects 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsMibRegistry ::= { netSnmpObjects 2 }
...
...
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogStatus ::= { nsLoggingEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogMaxLevel ::= { nsLoggingEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogType ::= { nsLoggingEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogToken ::= { nsLoggingEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogLevel ::= { nsLoggingEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendResult ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutNumLines ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutputFull ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput1Line ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutLine ::= { nsExtendOutput2Entry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendLineIndex ::= { nsExtendOutput2Entry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyStart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyShutdown ::= { netSnmpNotifications 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyRestart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laErrMessage ::= { laEntry 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laErrorFlag ::= { laEntry 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoadFloat ::= { laEntry 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoadInt ::= { laEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laConfig ::= { laEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoad ::= { laEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laNames ::= { laEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laIndex ::= { laEntry 1 }
```

I read the discussion on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257589/ubuntu-typing-php-in-terminal-shows-a-lot-of-errors) and the solution was to remove and reinstall `php`. I get `E: Unable to locate package php`. when I try to `remove` or `install` the package.

- I tried `purge`, with same response. I tried updating my repo, but still got the same response.
- I tried install/removing `php5`: this does go through, but the errors still display when I try `php` or `php5` in the terminal.
- I tried removing/reinstalling `php-snmp`. Again, this does reinstall, but the problem does not go away.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is getting downvotes? It is similar to the question posted, but the solution provided on that page does not work.

Comment: Probably because it's not really a programming related question. It's a server related problem

Comment: your question should be self contained, we should not have to visit other pages to understand what you are asking

Comment: Okay thanks, that makes sense. I'll move it to the right forum.

Comment: Why are you using `apt-get` to begin with if you don't even know the correct package name? Use `aptitude` or synaptic etc. The presented errors, btw, relate to the `snmp` extension. Randomly removing and reinstalling won't do you any favours.

Comment: The problem seems to be that removing/purging and then reinstalling has not done anything, since it resulted in an error - try `php5` instead. What version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: I was following the instruction provided as the solution for the EXACT problem another individual had. So naturally I did what worked for somebody else.

Comment: @Halfer, `php5` can be removed/reinstalled, but the problem still exists after. Typing `php` OR `php5` gives me that error. And I am running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=568550

Comment: @mario, you are a life saver! Post it, and I will vote it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo apt-get purge php5

try this command

Comment: I did, same response.

Comment: With `php5` it does remove and I can reinstall it. But the errors don't go away.

Comment: sudo apt-get install php5

Comment: try **sudo apt-get remove php5-snmp**